# JavaScript textarea get numbers of lines (with linebreaks)

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea and I want to know how many lines there are. Now I have searched but I only see this solution:

```
mytextarea.value.split("\n").length
```

Well, that works but that's not what I want.

For example my textarea is like this:

[image: textarea]

When I type this:

```
123456789abcdefghijkl
sasasasakasasask;as
```

When I use split("\n").value I get 2 which is correct but if I put this in:

```
123456789abcdefghijklsasasasasasasasasas
```

I get the result 1 which isn't correct:

[image: textarea without enters]

The result should be 2 because there are 2 lines however the line breaks are not created with `\n`.

Anyone an idea how you can calculate the number of lines INCLUDING the line breaks without `\n`?

Comment: Is the text actually on different lines? Or is it just wrapped aroound due to the size of the textarea?

Comment: you need to add the number of too long lines to the number of lines. if you hard-code a `cols`, then just divide the length of each line by that,  `Math.ceil()` the length, and add to the length of the line array. a monospace font is recommended.

Comment: I'm trying to make a plugin so I think someone can change the font.

Comment: @NeilDCruz yes it is wrapped around because of the size of the textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
static lineCaculator() {
            let dummy               = document.createElement('div');
            dummy.style.font        = AutoTextareaResizer.computedStyle.call(this, 'font');
            dummy.style.width       = AutoTextareaResizer.computedStyle.call(this, 'width');
            dummy.style.wordWrap    = 'break-word';
            dummy.innerHTML         = this.value;


            document.body.appendChild(dummy);

            let lines = parseInt(AutoTextareaResizer.computedStyle.call(dummy, 'height')) /  this.realLineHeight;

            document.body.removeChild(dummy);

            return Math.max(1, lines);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The end of each line, hit Enter . when you hit Enter ,insert \n to line.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="myTxt"></textarea>
        <button id ="btn" onclick="myLine()">Try</button>
        <p id="x"></p>
        <script>
           function myLine() {
               var txt = document.getElementById("myTxt");
               var x = document.getElementById("x"); 
               x.innerHTML =txt.value.split("\n").length;
           }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you type `123456789aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` it is still 1 but there are 2 lines,

Comment: @Dylan  yes , Because you dont hit enter and it dont fund \n.